# JavaScript way to define variable

Tags: javascript, function, callback

Hello I saw "this" *(now I just simplified it)* code on a website source. 

The question is:

Why is `this._position` defined with `m(p)` instead of just `p` ?

does it have some logical explanation ?

```
var emptyFunction = function j() {};
emptyFunction.thatReturnsValue = function(j) {
    return j;
};

var m = emptyFunction.thatReturnsValue;

function o(){
    this._position = 'left';
}
o.prototype.setPosition = function(p) {
    'use strict';

    this._position = m(p);
    return this;
};
o.prototype.getPosition = function(){
    return this._position;
}

function calculatePosition(oInst){
    var position;

    //( do some math to figure out the best position)
    position = 'right';
    oInst.setPosition(position);
}

function realWork(){
    var orientation = new o();
    calculatePosition(orientation);
    console.log(orientation.getPosition());
}
```

empty function is used for more things:

**

```
function h(j) {
    return function() {
        return j;
    };
}
var emptyFunction = function j() {};
emptyFunction.thatReturns = h;
emptyFunction.thatReturnsFalse = h(false);
emptyFunction.thatReturnsTrue = h(true);
emptyFunction.thatReturnsNull = h(null);
emptyFunction.thatReturnsThis = function() {
    return this;
};
emptyFunction.thatReturnsValue = function(j) {
    return j;
};
```

**

Comment: This is from a real website source, or from some kind of demo? It looks to me like it's just trying to show different ways to define a call a function. `m(p)` is the same as `p`.

Comment: @Barmar . they use emptyFunction  for more things  (updated post)

Comment: It doesn't matter what else they use `emptyFunction` for, it doesn't affect what `m(p)` does.

Comment: Basically, they're using `emptyFunction` as an object to hold a namespace. There's no reason for this, they're just trying to be clever or obscure.